How can I draw only the outer boundaries of a street network using OSMnx and Folium?
I would like to draw only the outer boundaries of the street network within a specific radius around a central point (latitude and longitude).
Currently, I'm using the following code to extract the street network and draw all the edges.
G2 = ox.graph_from_point((origin_latitude, origin_longitude), dist=1000, network_type="drive", simplify=True, truncate_by_edge=True)

[Example network]
(https://i.sstatic.net/UdlV2.png)
I have tried many times drawing the boundaries, but I keep with the same results.

"I have tried many times drawing the boundaries, but I keep with the same results." Please provide a minimal, reproducible, standalone code snippet that demonstrates the problem.
